# iOS : UITableView Reorder control not shown

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am setting up all the required properties to implement the reorder control for a `UITableView` in my iOS app, however the reorder control is not shown. Here's the code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return 4;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DragAndDrop";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Row %d", indexPath.row];
    cell.showsReorderControl=YES;
    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
         [tableView reloadData];
}
```

I have implemented all the required methods. Why is it not showing up?

Comment: Do you mean to say that when you tapped on a cell, it didnt show the reorder cell? Because you have added setEditing in didSelectRow method.

Comment: It does not show reordering controller anyway, I have tried it without the didSelectRow method.

Comment: In viewDidLoad, try this `[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to link the delegate in storyboard to the tableview. Everything is good now!!

Answer (score 3):

For that, you need to set "Edit" property of UITableView from start.

Hope it will be helpful to you.

Cheers!

Comment: I have tried adding [super setEditing:YES animated:YES] in the viewDidLoad method, but doesnt work agai..

Comment: Try with "viewDidLoad" method.

Answer (score 0):

try this  . . .this will handle arranging and updating of cell in case of simple tableview in editing mode

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
     [tableData insertObject: [tableData objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row] atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
     [tableData removeObjectAtIndex:(sourceIndexPath.row + 1)];
}
```